# Laptop changes from "Projector Only" to "Extend" by itself

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm using a laptop with an external monitor, and i use "Projector Only" to use the monitor. Then just like the title said, it randomly happen when i play game named "Kritika Online". I tried to leave my laptop turned on without playing that game (only showing desktop background), and nothing happen (normal). But when i played that game, it always happen (and it closes the game).

Anyone know what's wrong with my laptop? or is it my monitor? how can i fix it?

Comment: Does the same change the screen resolution to something the project cannot handle perhaps? Or maybe the monitor if that's what you have it connected to when it happens?

Comment: No, and the monitor always connected to my laptop. Because when it happen, the monitor isn't disconnected, but it changes to Extend mode.